# Changing position of indexes in a list

Tags: python, list

what would be the best way of swapping indices of list of undetermined length?  I want to swap the positions of the numbers in pairs, so that the first and second numbers are swapped, the third and fourth numbers are swapped, etc. The only way I know how to do it is as such:

```
   my_list[0], my_list[1] = my_list[1], my_list[0]
```

But I have no clue how to do so if the list is of undetermined length. A sample list would include [1,2,3,4] and would return [2,1,4,3]. But if it's odd, the last index of the list stays in the same position.

Comment: correct! this is the best python idiom for it.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do? If the list is of undetermined length, how would you know which elements you want to swap?

Comment: If the list is "of undetermined length", are you looking to *reverse* it, or swap the first and last element? Or something else altogether?

Comment: Sorry about that. I   want to swap the positions of the numbers in pairs, so that the first and second numbers are swapped, the third and fourth numbers are swapped, etc.

Comment: @charbs_33 - Edit the question to include that info. Better explicit than buried in the comments.

Comment: And include a sample list and desired resulting list to make it easy to test. And..., what happens for odd-length lists where they aren't all paired?

Comment: @tdelaney -  good point... thank you lol

Comment: Do you know about negative indexing?

Comment: @RicksupportsMonica - yes I  do a little bit of it

Comment: @RicksupportsMonica - would negative indexing help in some way?

Comment: The question was a bit confusing. It would only help if you know the index of what you are looking for counting from the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range(start, stop, step)` to index by twos. Then apply your existing pattern

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in range(0, len(my_list)-1, 2):
    my_list[i], my_list[i+1] = my_list[i+1], my_list[i]

assert my_list == [2, 1, 4, 3], "swapped okay"
```

Comment: this only seems to work for the first to indexes when I  try it

Comment: never mind, i   got it. thanks for your help1

Comment: @charbs_33 - glad it worked.

Comment: and I  assume that if the list is odd, I  can just make a simple if/else statement for it

Comment: @charbs_33 - No, that's why I added `len(my_list)-1`. If its an odd length list, the swapping will stop before the final value.

Answer (score 0):

First group the list in tuples of two elements

```
it = iter(my_list)
grouped = zip(it, it)
```

Now `grouped` is an iterator. It yields tuples of two elements.

Then join all the tuples reversing them:

```
new_list = [y for x in grouped for y in reversed(x)]
```

This add only pairs. If the list is odd then the last element is not added to new_list. So we put the last element in its place:

```
new_list[len(mylist)-1] = my_list[-1]
```

If it was already there nothing changes.

The first part (grouping) is rather obscure, but not difficult to understand. `zip` takes elements from each iterator in its arguments in turn and group them in tuples. But in this case I put the same iterator twice, so when zip takes the second iterator (which is the same as the first) it has already advance a place. So it groups in tuples of two elements because there are 2 iterators, but the elements are those from the unique iterator in order.

Comment: It's clever.. But it won't work when lst has odd numbers: eg `lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: Thank you. You are right. Y already ammended it